# Custom Image Attribute in random product_list

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm working with Magento 1.7.0.2 and I'm trying to display a custom image from my products in a random product_list.

First of all I added the attribute to all my sets and set a placeholder image.
In the database I searched for *used_in_product_listing* and set it to 1.

This is my **Product_List_Random** Class:

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Random extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) { 
            $categoryID = $this->getCategoryId();            
            if($categoryID)            {              
                $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
                $category->load($categoryID);
                $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
            } else { 
                $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection'); 
            }
            Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
            $collection->addStoreFilter();
            $numProducts = $this->getNumProducts() ? $this->getNumProducts() : 0;
            $collection->setPage(1, $numProducts)->load();

            $this->_productCollection = $collection;
        }
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
}
```

Here I tried to add `$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');` to get the url of the image in frontend.

This is what I tried so far in **frontend**:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):

    echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'specialprice_image')->resize(158, 270);

    echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('specialprice_image')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

    echo $_product->getAttributeText('specialprice_image');

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); ?>
    echo $product->getAttributeText('specialprice_image');
endforeach;
```

The helper is giving me the placeholder url. Ther other methods are giving me nothing.

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: Does the helper method not give you what you need, or are you just trying to understand why the others don't work?

Comment: I already have uploaded an image and selected in the productinformation. But the helper is giving me the URL to the placeholder instead of the URL to the selected image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works after editing the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Random Class

I just removed two lines of code:

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addStoreFilter();
```

The complete code:

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Random extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) { 
            $categoryID = $this->getCategoryId();            
            if($categoryID)            {              
                $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
                $category->load($categoryID);
                $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
            } else { 
                $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection'); 
            }
            Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
            $numProducts = $this->getNumProducts() ? $this->getNumProducts() : 0;
            $collection->setPage(1, $numProducts)->load();

            $this->_productCollection = $collection;
        }
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
}
```

And in frontend I'm using this code:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'specialprice_image')->resize(158, 270); ?>" width="158" height="270" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />
</a>
```